# Is BigQuery preview completely free?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Lets assume my table has 1 Trillion rows and currently Preview is showing 50 first results in a page.
If I go to the last 50 results (using the button already there), will I incur any cost? (as I am not querying anything)

Comment: Preview is free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @guillaumeblaquiere, **BigQuery Preview** is free.

You may refer to this [using preview options documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#preview-data) which also states,

> If you are experimenting with or exploring your data, you can use
> **table preview options to view data for free** and without affecting
> quotas.

For more detailes, refer to this [Control costs in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs) documentation for the best practices with regards to the costing of BigQuery.